# Dataframe Show all columns after dividing only specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

Below are the columns in my dataframe:

```
['Phone', 'Resolution', 'Detection for 1 person(s)',
   'Detection for 2 persons (s)', 'Recognition for 1 person(s)',
   'Recognition for 2 persons (s)']
```

Now for a given value of Phone in my dataframe, I want to divide the following columns:

```
['Detection for 1 person(s)', 'Detection for 2 persons (s)',
    'Recognition for 1 person(s)', 'Recognition for 2 persons (s)']
```

and then assign it back to the original dataframe. So I'm trying to perform this command:

```
df[df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7'][['Detection for 1 person(s)' , 'Detection for 2 persons (s)' , 'Recognition for 1 person(s)' , 'Recognition for 2 persons (s)']].div(1.14)
```

After doing this, my Jupyter notebook shows me the calculated Dataframe, but with only 4 columns as mentioned above. So while trying to assign it back to the original DF using:

```
df[df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7']] = df[df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7'][['Detection for 1 person(s)' , 'Detection for 2 persons (s)' , 'Recognition for 1 person(s)' , 'Recognition for 2 persons (s)']].div(1.14)
```

essentially puts out `NaN` on the columns Phone and Resolution.

Is there a way by which I can divide the columns I want but still restoring Phone and Resolution columns?

Comment: can you post a testable dataframe fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perhaps more readable way:

```
# Create a boolean mask 
mask = (df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7')

# A list of the columns to be divided
to_divide = ['Detection for 1 person(s)', 'Detection for 2 persons (s)',
    'Recognition for 1 person(s)', 'Recognition for 2 persons (s)']

# Divide the columns on the masked data
df.loc[mask, to_divide] /= 1.14
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Do you have a way where you could extend the mask. Like `mask = (df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7' && df['Resolution]='1920*1080')` ?

Comment: You're welcome! Close!: `mask = (df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7') & (df['Resolution'] == '1920*1080')`

Answer (score 1):

I think ( but without test I am not 100% sure) that you should had the columns your modifying also before the equal :

```
df[df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7']][['Detection for 1 person(s)' , 'Detection for 2 persons (s)' , 'Recognition for 1 person(s)' , 'Recognition for 2 persons (s)']] = df[df['Phone'] == 'Redmi Note 7'][['Detection for 1 person(s)' , 'Detection for 2 persons (s)' , 'Recognition for 1 person(s)' , 'Recognition for 2 persons (s)']].div(1.14)
```

But it is starting to be unreadable ;)

Answer (score 1):

## You can create a function to modify your dataframe. Here I modify the value of two columns when the value = 'Phone' = 'yes, but you can adjust to your dataframe.

```
    AAA BBB Phone   DDD EEE
0   x1  y1  yes     10  20
1   x1  y1  yes     10  20
2   x1  y1  no      10  20
3   x1  y2  no      10  20
4   x2  y2  yes     10  20
5   x2  y2  no      10  20

def convert_rows(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i,'Phone'] == 'yes':
            df.loc[i,'DDD'] =df.loc[i,'DDD']/1.4
            df.loc[i,'EEE'] =df.loc[i,'EEE']/1.4
        else:
            pass
    return df 

convert_rows(df)

    AAA BBB Phone   DDD     EEE
0   x1  y1  yes     7.14    14.29
1   x1  y1  yes     7.14    14.29
2   x1  y1  no      10.00   20.00
3   x1  y2  no      10.00   20.00
4   x2  y2  yes     7.14    14.29
5   x2  y2  no      10.00   20.00
```